# Deleted a bunch of fonts, iTunes interface is broken

Tags: windows-7, itunes

I use GIMP for graphic design and I've downloaded a lot of my own fonts. GIMP shows every single version of every font on Windows, including foreign ones, so I went into my registry and deleted all the fonts I thought I wouldn't use.

I still have many of the basics: Veranda, Lucidia Sans & Lucidia Grande, Trebuchet MS, Arial, I wouldn't delete those, but now my iTunes looks like this:

http://postimage.org/image/r5g1dyxj3/

I know a re-install might solve this problem, but does anyone know of an individual font that iTunes uses as their menu/sidebar font??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to overcome this is to copy the `FONTS` folder form another working system *of the same version of Windows* as what you're running.

On the good machine, open the Command Prompt, type `ROBOCOPY %windir%\Fonts x:\Fonts /s /xj /eta` and press Enter. Replace `X:\Fonts` with your removable drive. On the destination computer, type the opposite in an Administrative Command Prompt (`Start`->type `CMD` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>): `ROBOCOPY X:\Fonts %WINDIR%\Fonts /s /eta /xj` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

NOTE: If you are using Windows XP or lower, you will not have ROBOCOPY installed by default. In this case, use `COPY %WINDIR%\Fonts X:\Fonts /s` instead

Comment: I only had a Vista available but I did it and it worked. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search suggests that the fonts are likely Lucida Grande, Arial, Tahoma, and/or Trebuchet MS.  Since you listed all but Tahoma, I would suggest you put that one back on.

Comment: I've got Tahoma. I did the same Google search and I saw those, sorry I didn't list it up there. Thanks though!